# How do I fill null values of only selected columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe consists of  multiple columns with NaN values. I want to replace NaN values of only specific column ( column name: MarkDown1) with 0.

The statement I wrote is:

```
data1.loc[:,['MarkDown1']] = data1.loc[:,['MarkDown1']].fillna(0)
```

My statement is raising a warning:

```
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:965: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
    A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
    Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

    See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
    self.obj[item] = s
```

I request not not to mark my question as duplicate because I have referred the documentation and previous questions and have tried to implement the suggestions given. The suggestion was to use .loc. I have used .loc only in my code as mentioned above. But still I am getting the warning. Kindly suggest the correct syntax to eliminate the warning.

Comment: Try `data1['MarkDown1'] = data1['MarkDown1'].fillna(0)`

Comment: Try,    data1.loc[data1['MarkDown1'].isnull(), 'MarkDown1'] = 0

Comment: @Sociopath and Zoie. Tried the suggestions but still getting the warning.

Comment: u could just assign to the df : df = df.fillna({'MarkDown1':0}). Pass it in as a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of your problem is that you created *data1* probably
as a **view** of another DataFrame.

The result is that:

- *data1* is a separate DataFrame,
- but it shares its data buffer with another (source) DataFrame.

Example:

1. I created a DataFrame named *df* with the following content:

   ```
      Xxx  MarkDown1
   0    1       10.0
   1    2       20.0
   2    3        NaN
   3    4       30.0
   4    5       40.0
   ```
2. Then I created *data1* as a subset of *df*:

   ```
   data1 = df[df.Xxx < 5]
   ```

   Of course, *data1* contains now (actually presents) first 4 rows
   from *df*.
3. When I executed your instruction, your error message was presented.

To avoid it create *data1* as a **separate** DataFrame, **with its own data buffer**:

```
data1 = df[df.Xxx < 5].copy()
```

This time, when you run your instruction, no error occurs.

Comment: good idea, added new dupe.

Comment: Yes you are right. thanks for the insight you provided.